# Get the password in the form of stars

Tags: passwords

```
while(n != '\n')
{
    n = getch();
    printf("*");
}
```

/*I want to get the password and print the star, I use the getch function and print the password in the star, but what should I do to clear the character with ‌‌‌backspace?*/

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be backspace. Consider the following Python example:

```
print("Hello World", end="")
print("\bt ", end="")
```

With the `\b` one performs a backspace which allows a character to be overwritten. This is **not** a clear though. It only allows the terminal content to be overwritten. This is however not a safe method to perform such a task. In general it's not very ideal to use such a "*" method. Unix systems just hide the input[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html), which I would recommend.

This is **not** advice for security critical problems.